# how to pass variables between 2 bash scripts (export doesn't work)

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

here are 2 example scripts:
script.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
export TEST=1
```

script2.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
./script.sh
echo $TEST
```

`script.sh` is supposed to assign 1 to the TEST variable and `script2.sh` is supposed to run `script.sh` to assign 1 to the TEST variable and then print the value of the TEST variable (1).

that doesn't work for some reason.
there is no output, and if I run script.sh and then run echo $TEST it won't print anything - the variable is empty or nonexistent.

any idea why/how to do that properly?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Script 2 is written as calling itself. Please correct any unintentional mistake

Comment: @user414777 I accidentally put script2.sh as calling itself, thas not the case when I tested it.

Comment: Sub-processes cannot change environment variables or other stuff in their parent processes. You should source instead of running `script.sh` as a separate process: `. ./script.sh`.

Comment: @user414777 that worked, thanks a lot.